# What's wrong with my Fusion Drive?

Tags: mac-mini, core-storage, fusion-drive

I'm having weird issues with my internal Fusion Drive.

**Symptoms**:

1. It gave itself a new cryptical name, and I can't change it back
2. In most cases I cannot install new software anymore (e.g. I cannot update Flash)
3. It is sometimes shutting down immediately
4. Disk Utility says "no errors found" but can't mount it.

**See below for some screenshots:**

*Referring to Point 4 and 1* (says: Volume seems to be ok, see the weird name...)

[image: Disk Utility]

*Referring to Point 2* (says: Installation failed)

[image: Flash Player installer]

Error while mounting Flash Player installer image:

```
26.11.15 10:03:42,000 kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Adobe Flash Player Installer on device disk3s1
26.11.15 10:03:42,082 mds[55]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7fb9ef004600 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:1 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/Adobe Flash Player Installer
26.11.15 10:03:53,137 authexec[510]: executing /Volumes/Adobe Flash Player Installer/Install Adobe Flash Player.app/Contents/MacOS/Install Adobe Flash Player
26.11.15 10:04:14,000 kernel[0]: hfs: could not initialize summary table for Flash Player
26.11.15 10:04:14,000 kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Flash Player on device disk4s2
26.11.15 10:04:17,000 kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on Flash Player on device disk4s2
```

`diskutil cs list` output from Terminal:

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group BD4DE488-7C63-4FBA-9FAC-9B92CD56EDE4
=========================================================
Name:         FusionDrive
Status:       Online
Size:         1249060388864 B (1.2 TB)
Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
|
+-< Physical Volume C106FB79-47F5-4967-924F-043C553FC58E
|   ----------------------------------------------------
|   Index:    0
|   Disk:     disk0s2
|   Status:   Online
|   Size:     249715376128 B (249.7 GB)
|
+-< Physical Volume 6492048E-B397-4457-A12B-DA62DD379B35
|   ----------------------------------------------------
|   Index:    1
|   Disk:     disk1s2
|   Status:   Online
|   Size:     999345012736 B (999.3 GB)
|
+-> Logical Volume Family 40A9F389-D3F0-4D75-89A3-36FFAEA6FD57
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    Encryption Status:       Unlocked
    Encryption Type:         None
    Conversion Status:       NoConversion
    Conversion Direction:    -none-
    Has Encrypted Extents:   No
    Fully Secure:            No
    Passphrase Required:     No
    |
    +-> Logical Volume E02059A8-E5D4-4DFF-9D0F-49408380838E
        ---------------------------------------------------
        Disk:                  disk2
        Status:                Online
        Size (Total):          1242500358144 B (1.2 TB)
        Conversion Progress:   -none-
        Revertible:            No
        LV Name:               ´+ßPÜÜÜÜÜPÜ09O8UI9OOOOOOOIOO09O987UUUUZU6T786Z65444RRRR3ERR5EREREREER5R4E43E4ED43ERE3434R43RE3ER4E3R45REW4W45W343E43W424323231QWQ3W3W23432123432323E23E21W23453213E43212R2WEW1221QQ^21
        Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Output from Terminal for command `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`

```
     start       size  index  contents
         0          1         PMBR
         1          1         Pri GPT header
         2         32         Pri GPT table
        34          6         
        40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    409640  487725344      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 488134984     262144      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
 488397128          7         
 488397135         32         Sec GPT table
 488397167          1         Sec GPT header
```

Output from Terminal for command `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk1`

```
     start        size  index  contents
         0           1         PMBR
         1           1         Pri GPT header
         2          32         Pri GPT table
        34           6         
        40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    409640  1951845728      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
1952255368     1269760      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11- 00306543ECAC
1953525128           7         
1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
```

**My counteractions so far**

1. Ran the Apple Hardware Test. Result: nothing found.
2. Ran the First Aid (see screenshot). Result: nothing found.

---

No backup available!

Any help is much appreciated!

---

**Follow-up:**

The problem while trying to start a Backup you see below. This doesnt make sense, as the external drive has 999gb...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32174/discussion-on-question-by-fortun-whats-wrong-with-my-fusion-drive).

Comment: @klanomath I replied in the chat room. Not sure if that works

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. over 20 comments and 20 revisions is bumping this to the top of the page. Please try to simplify things @fortun and not keep stringing on the details. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your CoreStorage Logical Volume got corrupted!

I recommend to backup your data to an external drive with Time Machine and rebuild the FusionDrive from scratch.

**Time Machine backup**

- To backup your main volume, boot to your main drive
- Attach an external drive. The drive (or at least one volume) has to be formatted as an HFS+ Journaled volume. Check this with Disk Utility. If necessary repartition the external drive. All data on the drive will be destroyed after repartitioning/formatting it. The drive (or at least one volume) has to have the size of the volume to back up (or more).
- Usually you will be asked if the external drive should serve as a Time Machine backup drive after plugging it in for the first time. If not, open Time Machine in the *System Preferences* and configure the external drive as Time Machine backup drive.

  [image]

  Hit *Select Backup Drive* and choose your external drive:

  [image]

  Turn on Time Machine. The backup will be started after a few minutes and will take some time depending on the size.

**Rebuild Fusion Drive**

- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while starting your Mac.
- Booted to Internet Recovery Mode open Utilities → Terminal in the menubar and enter:
  `diskutil cs list` to get the CoreStorage listing.
- Copy the Logical Volume UUID, it's the fifth listed.
- Now delete the Logical Volume with `diskutil cs deleteVolume LVUUID`.
  In your case that's `diskutil cs deleteVolume E02059A8-E5D4-4DFF-9D0F-49408380838E`
- Copy the Logical Volume Group UUID, it's the first listed in the listing of `diskutil cs list`.
- Then delete the Logical Volume Group with `diskutil cs delete LVGUUID`.
  In your case that's `diskutil cs delete BD4DE488-7C63-4FBA-9FAC-9B92CD56EDE4E`
- Enter exit and quit 'Terminal'
- Open 'Disk Utility'. Enter 'Ignore' if you are asked to fix the drives.
- Choose your SSD and partition it: 1 Partition Mac OS X Extended (Journaled),
  hit the Options button and choose GUID Partiton table and hit OK and Apply.
  Please check that the size is ~250 GB

  Example:

  [image: ssd]
- Choose your HDD and partition it: 1 Partition Mac OS X Extended (Journaled),
  hit the Options button and choose GUID Partiton table and hit OK and Apply.
  Please check that the size is ~1 TB

  Example:

  [image: hdd]
- Quit Disk Utility and open Terminal
- Enter `diskutil list`

  Example (your disk identifiers and sizes are different of course: Your volume SSD probably has the Identifier disk0s2 and the size 250 GB and your volume HDD probably has the Identifier disk1s2 and the size 1.0 TB):

  [image: diskutil]
- Enter `diskutil cs create "Name" IdentifierSSD IdentifierHDD`
  In your case probably `diskutil cs create "FusionDrive" disk0s2 disk1s2`.

  Copy the resulting LVGUUID

  Example:

  [image: cscreate]
- Enter `diskutil cs CreateVolume LVGUUID jhfs+ "FusionDrive" 100%`.

  Example:

  [image: lvcreate]
- Enter `diskutil cs list`
  Check the size of your Logical Volume. It should have the size ~1.250 TB

  Example:

  [image: diskcslist]
- Quit Terminal
- Open 'Disk Utility' and check your newly created volume for errors
- Quit 'Disk Utility'

**Restore Time Machine backup**

- Attach your external Time Machine backup drive or check this [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRBJV.png) if you use NAS or another network share.
- Open 'Restore from Time Machine Backup'
- Choose the appropriate Time Machine backup and restore your system
- Reboot to your restored system.
- Unmount and detach your Time Machine backup drive
- Open 'Terminal' and enter 'diskutil list'
- Check if your 'Recovery HD' is listed.
- If your 'Recovery HD' is missing, usually reinstalling your current system with the latest available system installer (e.g. 'Install OS X Yosemite (10.10.5)' if Yosemite is currently installed) will recreate it without loosing any data.
- After reinstalling the system with the latest available system installer open `App Store` and install the latest security fixes.

**Restore from other sources**

If you don't have a Time Machine backup or another appropriate backup, you have to install the system manually.

- Booted to Internet Recovery Mode choose "Restore OS X" (or something similar). This will download and install the original OS X coming with your Mac.
- After installing OS X configure your Mac with your common user. Download and upgrade to the appropriate system (in your case probably 10.10.5). If you haven't "purchased" (it is or was free) OS X Yosemite with your Apple App Store account you are lost and you have to get it from somewhere else.
- After upgrading to OS X Yosemite attach your external drive and open the *restore image*.
- Copy all necessary files & folders in your old user folder to your new account. Avoid overwriting existing folders of your new account! Also check your old /Users/your_user_name/Library folder (which usually is invisible!).
- Download and reinstall all needed applications.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32175/discussion-on-answer-by-klanomath-whats-wrong-with-my-fusion-drive).